# How to separate and reposition select parts of image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

**Problem**

I have a image with five separate icons i wish to separate and reposition. How would i achieve this? Would i use layers? and if so how do i put each icon into a layer.

(REPHRASED QUESTION)

i'm not really sure layers is the approach i need. But i wish to separate this png into 6 blocks each containing the different logos shown. I then would like to be able to move them around at will until i'm happy with their position and export

**Image**

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you give more details? Is your source image a JPG, or PSD? (As in, are there layers to work with?) I'm just a little confused about what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Johannes it's a png, i'm not really sure layers is the approach i need. But i wish to separate this png into 6 blocks each containing the different logos shown. I then would like to be able to move them around at will until i'm happy with their position and export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first separate the elements you'd like to move into Photoshop layers.

1. You should use the elliptical marquee tool (hold down the shift key) to select perfect circles.
2. Once you select one circle press Cntrl J that will create a new layer with just the area you've selected
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 for all the objects you need on separate layers
4. Move the objects as needed
5. Export them as separate files using slices or by copying and pasting into new files.

Comment: "elliptical marqueee tool" Shouldn't you use the elliptical marqueeeeeeeee tool, instead?